# Why does Microsoft std::vector::insert use rotate()?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, vector, stl

I was doing some experiments with lists vs vectors, and I noticed that the Microsoft implementation of std::vector is doing the following for .insert:

```
iterator insert(const_iterator _Where, _Ty&& _Val)
    {   // insert by moving _Val at _Where
    return (emplace(_Where, _STD move(_Val)));
    }

    iterator emplace(const_iterator _Where \
        COMMA LIST(_TYPE_REFREF_ARG)) \
    {   /* insert by moving _Val at _Where */ \
    size_type _Off = _VIPTR(_Where) - this->_Myfirst; \
    _VECTOR_EMPLACE_CHECK \
    emplace_back(LIST(_FORWARD_ARG)); \
    _STD rotate(begin() + _Off, end() - 1, end()); \
    return (begin() + _Off); \
    }
```

I could not figure out what rotate does in vs2012, but in 2015 does this:

```
template<class _RanIt> inline
    _RanIt _Rotate(_RanIt _First, _RanIt _Mid, _RanIt _Last,
        random_access_iterator_tag)
    {   // rotate [_First, _Last), random-access iterators
    _STD reverse(_First, _Mid);
    _STD reverse(_Mid, _Last);
    _STD reverse(_First, _Last);
    return (_First + (_Last - _Mid));
    }

// TEMPLATE FUNCTION reverse
template<class _BidIt> inline
    void _Reverse(_BidIt _First, _BidIt _Last, bidirectional_iterator_tag)
    {   // reverse elements in [_First, _Last), bidirectional iterators
    for (; _First != _Last && _First != --_Last; ++_First)
        _STD iter_swap(_First, _Last);
    }
```

This is not an optimal way to traverse memory if we think about our cache.

I did some benchmarks, where I held the element in a temporary and used that to swap elements and it was faster:
This was it:

```
push_back(value); //My vector doesn't have resize/grow implemented
T tmp = *(end() - 1);
while(new_location != end())
{
    std::swap(tmp, *new_location);
    new_location++;
}
```

The full code and tests are [here](https://github.com/AlexEne/Presentations-2016/blob/master/Memory/list_vs_vector.cpp).

First question:

***Why does it do that rotate instead of the second version of insert that I presented here?***

The second version is a more cache-friendly alternative compared with the first one. For large vectors swapping with the last element in the vector introduces a time penalty due to the cache.

***Is it in order to avoid storing another temporary?***

Second question:

***Why doesn't it just memmove the elements one position to the right?***

***Is there a standard requirement that forces you to swap elements instead of calling memmove?***
It's interesting that for POD there is not a special template specialization that just memmoves stuff around. In any case I am more interested in why rotate and not a more cache friendly alternative is used.

In my tests this is even faster than the previous two versions.

Tests are done like this:

0) for i = 0 to count

1) Pick a random position in a vector

2) Touch each element from 0 to that position (force a read on it)

3) Call insert after we reach the position

Compiled with Visual Studio 2012 x86, /O2.

```
For count = 100 000, element size = 4 bytes:

std::vector:                7.5 seconds   
std::list:                 19.6 seconds                            
MyVector:                   3.2 seconds                              
MyVector using memmove:     2.1 seconds

For count = 200 000, element size = 4 bytes:
std::vector:                30.3 seconds                          
std::list:                  45.5 seconds                          
MyVector:                   13.1 seconds
MyVector using memmove:      8.7 seconds   

For count = 20 000, element size = 128 bytes:
std::vector:                5.36 seconds
std::list:                  1.37 seconds
MyVector:                   5.12 seconds
MyVector (memmove)          1.68 seconds
```

*I know this is not a real life thing that you would do, these were some experiments that I did in order to show that cache matters, and I accidentally discovered the way that std vector insert works.*

***Also I know MyVector is a bad implementation of a vector. I just quickly wrote it in order to test my assumptions for insert. I just want to discuss the insert() implementation, not Vector class design :).***

Thanks for reading this

Comment: you can't `memmove` objects that are not of POD type

Comment: I see, i suspected that, but it's strange that they did not create memmove specialized versions for pod.

Comment: Polite request: Could you fix your demo code to a) not use `conio.h`, and b) include all the headers it needs (e.g. for `memset`)?

Comment: Ups, Sure. I quickly coded it in Visual Studio and didn't properly check my includes. I will fix it when I get home.

Comment: FWIW, libc++ first creates the temporary (initialized with the arguments passed to emplace), then moves back a range in the vector to make space and finally move-assigns from the temporary to the destination element.

Comment: libstdc++ OTOH first moves the range backwards to make space, then inserts the element, using no temporary (this is not as exception-safe as what libc++ is doing, where the latter explicitly adjusted the order of these operations).

Comment: @AlexandruEne: Did you actually look at the library implementation of `rotate`? It's been a while since I looked at VS2012 but I don't remember any of the overloads doing a "swap with the last element in a loop".

Comment: The definition of rotate from here ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate )  says it should do that, given the arguments that vc++ calls it with. visual's implementation is hard to follow, but I will try to post the relevant piece of code when I get home.
The call to rotate posted above is: rotate(begin() + _Off, end() - 1, end())

Comment: (Your code still [doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/HBIhcZ) :-(.)

Comment: There is a good chance that something inside `rotate` eventually has specializations to detect PODs and use `memmove` accordingly. It makes sense to put these specializations into functions such as `copy` and `swap` instead of specializing every single algorithm.

Comment: I an wondering why rotate for random iterators is doing 3 reverses. That is the normal implementation of rotate for bi-directonal iterators. rotate for random iterators normally rotates individual elements having found the gcd (Euclid algorithm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that there is no particular reason to call rotate in std::vector::insert.

I'll paste here the rotate implementation for visual studio 2015 that is used in insert():

```
template<class _RanIt> inline
    _RanIt _Rotate(_RanIt _First, _RanIt _Mid, _RanIt _Last,
        random_access_iterator_tag)
    {   // rotate [_First, _Last), random-access iterators
    _STD reverse(_First, _Mid);
    _STD reverse(_Mid, _Last);
    _STD reverse(_First, _Last);
    return (_First + (_Last - _Mid));
    }

// TEMPLATE FUNCTION reverse
template<class _BidIt> inline
    void _Reverse(_BidIt _First, _BidIt _Last, bidirectional_iterator_tag)
    {   // reverse elements in [_First, _Last), bidirectional iterators
    for (; _First != _Last && _First != --_Last; ++_First)
        _STD iter_swap(_First, _Last);
    }
```

A more cache friendly implementation will increase the speed of this method (vector::insert).

I know because people from Microsoft's STL are aware of the issue :)

https://twitter.com/StephanTLavavej/status/695013465342083072